# Install Java JDK 1.8 on CentOS using Chef

Tags: java, java-8, chef-infra, devops, cookbook

I'm trying to install Java JDK 1.8 on CentOS 7 using a Chef Cookbook.

I'm using Chef DK on Windows 10 and I've donloaded from https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk

In my `Berksfile` I've

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
metadata
```

My `Kitchen.yml` is the follow

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  # You may wish to disable always updating cookbooks in CI or other testing environments.
  # For example:
  #   always_update_cookbooks: <%= !ENV['CI'] %>
  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: centos-7

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[test::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/integration/default
    attributes:
```

My `metadata.rb` is the follow

```
name 'test'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'All Rights Reserved'
description 'Installs/Configures test'
long_description 'Installs/Configures test'
version '0.1.0'
chef_version '>= 12.14' if respond_to?(:chef_version)

depends 'java', '~> 2.2.0'
```

My `recipes/default.rb`

```
node.default["java"]["install_flavor"] = "oracle"
node.default["java"]["jdk_version"]    = "8"
node.default['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true

include_recipe "java"
```

and its `attributes/recipe.rb`

```
default['java']['install_flavor'] = 'oracle'
default['java']['jdk_version'] = '8'
default['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
```

When I try to execute `kitchen converge` the output is

```
-----> Starting Kitchen (v1.22.0)
-----> Converging <default-centos-7>...
       Preparing files for transfer
       Preparing dna.json
       Resolving cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf 7.0.4...
       Removing non-cookbook files before transfer
       Preparing validation.pem
       Preparing client.rb
-----> Chef Omnibus installation detected (install only if missing)
       Transferring files to <default-centos-7>
       Starting Chef Client, version 14.3.37
       resolving cookbooks for run list: ["test::default"]
       Synchronizing Cookbooks:
         - windows (5.0.0)
         - homebrew (5.0.4)
         - test (0.1.0)
         - java (2.2.0)
       Installing Cookbook Gems:
       Compiling Cookbooks...

       ================================================================================
       Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/test/recipes/default.rb
       ================================================================================

       NoMethodError
       -------------
       undefined method `java_oracle_install' for cookbook: java, recipe: oracle :Chef::Recipe

       Cookbook Trace:
       ---------------
         /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/java/recipes/oracle.rb:40:in `from_file'
         /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/java/recipes/default.rb:22:in `from_file'
         /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/test/recipes/default.rb:8:in `from_file'

       Relevant File Content:
       ----------------------
       /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/java/recipes/oracle.rb:

        33:  version = node['java']['jdk_version'].to_s
        34:  tarball_url = node['java']['jdk'][version][arch]['url']
        35:  tarball_checksum = node['java']['jdk'][version][arch]['checksum']
        36:  bin_cmds = node['java']['jdk'][version]['bin_cmds']
        37:
        38:  include_recipe 'java::set_java_home'
        39:
        40>> java_oracle_install 'jdk' do
        41:    url tarball_url
        42:    default node['java']['set_default']
        43:    checksum tarball_checksum
        44:    app_home java_home
        45:    bin_cmds bin_cmds
        46:    alternatives_priority node['java']['alternatives_priority']
        47:    retries node['java']['ark_retries']
        48:    retry_delay node['java']['ark_retry_delay']
        49:    connect_timeout node['java']['ark_timeout']

       System Info:
       ------------
       chef_version=14.3.37
       platform=centos
       platform_version=7.5.1804
       ruby=ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
       program_name=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
       executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client


       Running handlers:
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
       Running handlers complete
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
       Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 04 seconds
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `java_oracle_install' for cookbook: java, recipe: oracle :Chef::Recipe
       [2018-08-21T17:23:54+00:00] FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `java_oracle_install' for cookbook: java, recipe: oracle :Chef::Recipe
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: 1 actions failed.
>>>>>>     Converge failed on instance <default-centos-7>.  Please see .kitchen/logs/default-centos-7.log for more details
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your error, but without luck, centos 7.5 (I think it is the same image as centos 7), java cookbook 2.2.0, chef 14.3.37 :/ The only difference in my case is newer version of test-kitchen (1.23.2). Have you tried different version of chefdk? I do not see anything particular in chefdk or test-kitchen changelogs but I am out of ideas.

Comment: I'm using Chef DK on Windows and I've download ed it from official site... how may I update my test kitchen version?

Comment: I am not sure, I do not use chefdk. You may try to ask on [Chef's slack #chef-dk or #general channel](https://community-slack.chef.io/).

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts (supported also by the Slack Chef chat ...), I've solved: I'm not sure how general is this solution but it works.

The problem is a about execution of the command `kitchen converge`.

I've noticed that when it fails with the message `warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block` this generate (I don't kno why ...), INSIDE the cookbook some directories (in my case, `java`, `windows`, `homebrew`, ecc .. ), and this was quite strange.

What I've done:

1. Submit the command `kitchen destroy`
2. Cleared out my berks cache `C:\Users\USERNAME\.berkshelf`
3. Submit the command `kitchen create`
4. Submit the command `kitchen converge`
5. If the error `warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block` compare and some strange directory is generated inside the cookbook, delete them (MANUALLY).
6. Check that the Chef supermarket cookbook are downloaded in
   `C:\Users\USERNAME\.berkshelf` (in my case `homebrew-5.0.4`,
   `java-2.2.0`, `tomcat-3.0.0` and `windows-5.0.0`)
7. Repeat the command `kitchen converge` until no error is generated

In this way oracle java jdk 1.8 has been installed on my CentOS 7 target node

I hope this could be useful for others